# Does rails continue to process a controller method if the page/form that called it is user closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(rails 2.3.5)

I have a model that when saved creates a long series associated records (4-8 second delay).   If a user were to close the page during this delay, does the contoller finish running the called method ('new', whatever...) until complete?

I'm assuming (hoping) 'yes'.  I just wanted to make sure and can't figure out how to google this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the processing is in the model than yes, that being said you should consider why it takes that long to create a record and maybe offload it to background processor such as resqueue , background-job or sidekiq